# Instruments crashed at start up

Tags: appium

I am running appium server 1.2 at MAC OS 10.8.X and appis installed on real iOs device Iphone 5.
When I try to run the test script, it gives me the following error.

```
info: [debug] App is installed.

info: [debug] fullReset not requested. No need to install.
info: [debug] Starting command proxy.

info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Starting instruments

info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments

info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 1d30758b4d21c267fb261c47d52b1e393357367e
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 1d30758b4d21c267fb261c47d52b1e393357367e com.equinix.ecpnewappdistribution -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/anujtomar/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-0943baae6b1d6f5b.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2014-12-10 15:18:14.827 instruments[6611:707] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'Equinix's iPhone (v8.0.2)' (The service is invalid.)

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2014-12-10 15:18:14.954 instruments[6611:2203] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'Equinix's iPhone (v8.0.2)' (The service is invalid.)

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253

info: [debug] Killall instruments
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with device. Try below steps:

- Open Xcode
- Goto Window
- Organizer
- Under you device name goto Console.
- Clear the the console.
- And then run test cases again.

Hope that helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem and none of the above techniques worked.
However I was able to  run appium by doing the following changes in the setting

- choose xcode instruments
- choose automation
- Look for options and select allow device for automation
- A window comes up asking for permission. Select 'okay' and you should be able to run appium now